# jQuery: Each Loop Oddity

Tags: loops, coffeescript

I want to go through all fields of a form and determine if the fields are populated with data. When all fields are given, I'd like a button `save` to appear.

## [This is the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwmk3ha1/3) with code, that works (!) ...

## [This is the same in JavaScript](https://jsfiddle.net/zpzkabmz/).

The **jQuery-Object** to iterate through:

```
formElements = $ 'form input[type="text"], form input[type="number"], form textarea'
```

The **Function**:

```
formFilled = ->
  filled = true
  formElements.each ->
    if $(this).val().length is 0
      filled = false
  filled
```

The **Event-Handler**:

```
formElements.on 'keyup', (keyup) ->
  keyup.preventDefault()
  if formFilled()
    save.show()
  else
    save.hide()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: the save button `save` never shows up (is hidden all the time) ...

Comment: There's nothing that's asynchronous here. Does your `keyup` handler get called at all? Does `formElements` actually have anything in it?

Comment: @Timo I see you've thrown a lot of questions up in the last 24 hours on this. Could you create a [JS fiddle|https://jsfiddle.net/] including your coffeescript and html? We really need to see the whole code to figure this out. And you can insert coffeescript into the fiddle by clicking on the `javascript` text in the bottom left text area

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mwmk3ha1/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## # I know the answer:

**JavaScript** *validates* the **number-input** fields and accepts only values that are numbers.

I stupidly tested those fields with text input ... silly.

The code is fine. Just the testing was bad. Sorry for wasting your time.

## This works:

```
formInputs = $ 'input[type="text"], input[type="number"], textarea'

formFilled = ->
  filled = true
  formInputs.each ->
    if $(this).val().length is 0
      filled = false
  filled

formInputs.on 'keyup', (keyup) ->
  if formFilled()
    saveButton.show()
  else
    saveButton.hide()
```